# sql error procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

What's wrong with this code?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Proc
( 
     @factura_id int, @produs_id int, @pret float, @cantitate int,@nr_ordine int
)
as
--declare @factura_id int, @produs_id int, @nr_ordine int, @pret float,  @cantitate int
begin
    if(((select COUNT (id_produs) from Produse where id_produs=@produs_id)=1))
        insert into FacturaProdus(id_factura,id_produs,pret,cantitate,nr_ordine) 
        values(@factura_id,@produs_id,@pret, CONCAT ('-',convert(float,@cantitate),@nr_ordine))
    else
    begin
        print 'hei'
    end
end
```

I can't find a solution for this.When i execute it, it gives me:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Proc'.
>   Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 8
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@produs_id".
>   Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 9
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@factura_id".

What to do?

Answer (score 3):

`Proc` is [reserved word](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) in SQL server (I assume you're using it based on syntax and error messages).

So if you really want to create procedure having such a name (I recommend you to choose another name, though) - enclose it into square brackets:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Proc]
(
 .....
```